# AutoCAD Command Rejected: "Undo" when calling undo from LISP

Tags: c#, .net, lisp, autolisp

I've been trying for the past 3 weeks to be able to call undo commands programmatically. My latest attempt involves invoking LISP code from C#. Right now my C# Method looks like this

```
[CommandMethod("TestLispFromC#", CommandFlags.Modal)]
    public void TestLisp()
    {
        ResultBuffer lispFunctionCallWithArguments = new ResultBuffer(new TypedValue((int)LispDataType.Text, "BIGUNDO")); // build the arguments list
        ResultBuffer resultOfLispFunction = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.Invoke(lispFunctionCallWithArguments); // call the LISP fuction anf get the return value
        _editor.WriteMessage(resultOfLispFunction.ToString()); //print the result
    }
```

And the Lisp functions I want to invoke come from here

(defun BIGUNDO ()
  (command "undo" "b")
)

(defun MARKPOS ()
    (command "undo" "m")
)

(vl-acad-defun 'BIGUNDO)

(vl-acad-defun 'MARKPOS)

The command makes it to AutoCAD but I'm greeted with an error saying "AutoCAD Command rejected: "undo"". I don't know how to get AutoCAD to accept a programmatic undo command.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define with **c:**

Please try the following:

(defun c:BIGUNDO()(command "undo" "b" "Y"))

Note the "Y" at the end because it asks *This will undo everything. OK?*